# How to pass a std::sync::mpsc::Sender<T> to a handler in warp?

Tags: rust, async-await, move-semantics, rust-warp

In warp (rust), how can I pass a `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<T>` to my business handlers? The following codes complains that `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<T>` is not `Sync`.

I understand that I possibly could wrap `my_sender` with something like `Arc<RwLock<Sender<T>>>`, but that doesn't seem right, since the purpose of channel is to enable inter-threads communication.

Do I have to wrap the `Sender<T>`, or there is a better way to do this?

```
use std;
use warp::{self, Filter};

fn with_sender<T: Send + Sync>(
    sender: std::sync::mpsc::Sender<T>,
) -> impl Filter<Extract = (std::sync::mpsc::Sender<T>,), Error = std::convert::Infallible> + Clone
{
    warp::any().map(move || sender.clone())
}

// later in main():
let (my_sender, my_receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel::<MySyncAndSendType>();

let routes = (warp::get()
    .and(warp::path!("some" / "path"))
    .map(my_handlers::handler_1)
    .map(turn_result_to_json)
    .or(warp::post()
        .and(warp::path!("some" / "other" / "path"))
        .and(warp::multipart::form().max_length(10 * 1024 * 1024))
        .and(with_sender(my_sender.clone()))
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // -------> I need my_sender in the function my_handlers::handler_2 <-------
        .and_then(|form, my_sender| async move {
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(my_handlers::handler_2(form, my_sender).await)
        })
        .map(turn_result_to_json)));

warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 1234)).await;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sender` is not `Sync`, so it cannot be shared, but it *is* `Send`, so you *can* `move` it into the async task.

The problem with your code is that the closure is capturing its environment by reference, even though the `async` block inside is `move`. You should just need to make the closure `move` too:

```
.and_then(move |form, my_sender| async move {
    Ok::<_, Infallible>(my_handlers::handler_2(form, my_sender).await)
})
```